# Opening a HEVC video causes various warnings

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm having a little problem with opening a file with ffmpeg.

It *can* open it, but produces some warnings and I wish to make it perfect because now, ffmpeg can only transcode at 0.7x, and I might get better results if the input is properly recognized and set.

Here is my command and the warnings:

```
$ ffmpeg -benchmark -vcodec hevc_rkmpp -i ../DJI_0181.MP4 -vf 'scale_rga' -vcodec h264_rkmpp -q:v 80 -f null -
ffmpeg version N-104499-g646d5566ac Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-lzma --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-outdevs --disable-libx264 --disable-libopenh264 --disable-decoder=h264_v4l2m2m --disable-decoder=vp8_v4l2m2m --disable-decoder=mpeg2_v4l2m2m --disable-decoder=mpeg4_v4l2m2m --enable-lto --enable-neon --enable-vfp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libdrm --enable-libopus --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-librga --enable-rkmpp
  libavutil      57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 16.100 /  8. 16.100
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x557af682a0] stream 0, timescale not set
[hevc @ 0x557af7ca40] PPS id out of range: 65498
[hevc @ 0x557af7ca40] Error parsing NAL unit #0.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x557af682a0] Stream #4: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x557af682a0] decoding for stream 4 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x557af682a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../DJI_0181.MP4':
```

As you can see there are 4 problems:

1. timescale not set
2. PPS id out of range: 65498
3. not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
4. Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Video: hevc, none): unspecified size

I tried to increase probesize, but might put it into wrong place, please help me resolving these issues.